# KDE Tray. How to raise a window from system tray?

Tags: kde

`wmctrl -l` doesn't inlude the programs from the system tray.

I want to add a keyboard shortcut to open a program being placed to system tray (ktimetracker).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

I solved my case, not a general approach.

It seems a QT-based application can be raised from tray. But in my case though there was a `setFocus` method, it didn't work.

So I ended up with a solution working for me.

```
ktimetracker; qdbus-qt5 org.kde.ktimetracker /ktimetracker/MainWindow_1 show; wmctrl -a "KTimeTracker"
```

`ktimetracker` - will start if not started.

`qdbus-qt5 org.kde.ktimetracker /ktimetracker/MainWindow_1 show` - use dbus to show the window, but still unfocused.

And `wmctrl -a "KTimeTracker"` to focus on it (now `wmctrl` is able to see the window.

I use the script for a keyboard shortcut to raise my window from tray.